# Reload page if element does not show - Codeception

Tags: codeception

So I'm trying to make codeception reload my page if it does not see an element.

```
if ($I->dontSeeElement('body > div.site > main > header > h1'))
{
    $I->reloadPage();
}
```

I have this set in the `_after` function.

But every time I run my test, it throws me an error.
My logic is: If it does see that element, it should just move on. If not, then reload page.

Comment: You will need to create a helper function that returns a boolean. You can use $I->dontSeeElement() in that function and catch the exception that will be thrown.

Comment: Besides that, the _after function seems to be the wrong place to use it, since that will be called after the test.

Comment: Where would you call it ?

Comment: Inside the test, wherever you think you should reload the page if that element is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to extend your acceptance tester class with something like this:

```
public function reloadIfElementNotFound($selector)
{
    try {
        $this->seeElement($selector);
    } catch (\PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException $e) {
        $this->reloadPage();
        $this->seeElement($selector);
    }
}
```

So, it will try to "see" an element, and if it's not found then a `\PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException` will be thrown, which you're going to `catch` and then reload the page. Also, make sure that the element is then visible after the reload. However, if it's still not visible after the reload, then the exception will be thrown again and break the test, which - I guess - would be the desired behavior.

In your test you'd then simply use:

```
$I->reloadIfElementNotFound('body > div.site > main > header > h1');
```