# Check if an element is there but do not fail if it's not codeception

Tags: codeception

Is there a native way in codeception to just check for the presence of an element without failing the test if element is not found?

I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908309/reload-page-if-element-does-not-show-codeception) which uses try/catch, but isn't there a native way of doing this?

```
    try {
        $this->seeElement($selector);
    } catch (\PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException $e) {
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's no other way, so here's a little function that you can use. Pass it valid xpath through `$element` and `$I` is your codeception object

```
    /**
     * If element is found return true if not return false
     * @param $element
     * @return bool
     */
    public function elementIsPresent($I, $element)
    {
        try {
            $I->seeElement($element);
            $isFound = true;
        } catch (\PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException $e) {
            $isFound = false;
        }
        return $isFound;
    }
```

for simple text swap `seeElement` for `see`